# Excel VBA Nested Array to provide user name choices based on section choice

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, validation

I am trying to (eventually) fill a data validation with specific choices, based on the users selection in the first (or main) data validation box. Currently I need to get this nested array sorted out, as I believe it will be the first step to solving this problem. However, I cannot get this nested array to populate. Thank you in advance!

```
Sub Test_NestedArray()

Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheet("EOS Report")

Dim Array_Machine_List_Choices As Variant

Dim Array_Fab
Dim Array_Paint
Dim Array_Sub
Dim Array_Asy
Dim Array_Facilities

Array_Fab = Array(Range(MACHINESFAB)) 'referencing named ranges on the sheet
Array_Paint = Array(RANGE(MACHINESPAINT))
Array_Sub = Array(RANGE(MACHINESSUB))
Array_Asy = Array(RANGE(MACHINESASY))
Array_Facilities = Array(RANGE(MACHINESFACILITIES)

Array_Machine_List_Choices = Array(Array_Fab, Array_Paint, Array_Sub, Array_Asy, Array_Facilities)

MsgBox (Array_Machine_List_Choices(1)) 'see the array choices for Paint

End Sub
```

Comment: You're setting your Arrays correctly. They should be set like `Array_Fab = Range("MACHINESFAB").Value2` Also, these will be 2D Arrays not 1D so will need to be referenced as such e.g. `MsgBox Array_Machine_List_Choices(1)(1,1)`

Comment: or `Array_Fab = [transpose(MACHINESFAB)]` for 1D array, but Data Validation formulas can be used instead of the unreliable VBA that may not be allowed to run on the user machine http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: on the `Array_Fab = Array(Range("MACHINESFAB")).Value2` I get error 1004, method range of object _global failed

Comment: @mitchmitch24 Where did the `Array()` come from? It's not in my example. And also yes to @Slai's mention. You can convert the Range to a 1D array by transposing it. You may have to double transpose depending on your data structure

Comment: I changed them to the [transpose ... but now I get runt time error 9, script out of range for `MsgBox (Array_Machine_List_Choices(1)(1,1))`

Comment: Check what is in your arrays in the Locals window. If you've transposed them they may be 1D so you'll refer to them as `Array_Machine_List_Choices(1)(1)` Also, You don't need to wrap it in brackets

Comment: `Array` index starts from 0, and excel range array index from 1, so probably `MsgBox Array_Machine_List_Choices(0)(1)`

Comment: You can change the Array Index to start at 1 by default by putting `Option Base 1` at the top of your module so that they match if you wish

Comment: @Tom, I totally messed that up. Changing it to what you actually had worked out. The only question I have left, is that the message box only gives me one of the values. How can I make it show each value (for paint)? There are three, but it only displayed the first one.

Comment: Try using `MsgBox Join(Array_Machine_List_Choices(1), vbNewLine)` If they're in 1D arrays. You can change the seperator (`vbNewLine`) to whatever you want. If they are in 2D arrays (although it would be better to use @Slai suggestion and transpose them) You could use `MsgBox Join(Application.Index(Array_Machine_List_Choices(1), 0, 1), vbNewLine))` Or `MsgBox Join(Application.Index(Array_Machine_List_Choices(1), 1, 0), vbNewLine))` Depending on your array structure

Comment: Hi Tom, the MsgBox Join(Application.Index(Array_Machine_List_Choices(1), 1, 0), vbNewLine)) displays just the first one again. The other two throw that run time error. The arrays are listed each in their own column, with different values in each row of that specific column.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback! It is really helpful and I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un/comment as necessary. Hopefully though this shows what you need a little bit more then the comments

```
Sub Test_NestedArray()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Array_Fab As Variant, Array_Paint As Variant, Array_Sub As Variant
    Dim Array_Asy As Variant, Array_Facilities As Variant, Array_Machine_List_Choices As Variant

    Set ws = Worksheets("EOS Report")
    ' Assuming all your ranges are in this worksheet. If not delete the With and the End With and the .'s in front of Range
    With ws
'        ' If data is in a single row with multiple columns
'        Array_Fab = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("MACHINESFAB"))) 'referencing named ranges on the sheet
'        Array_Paint = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("MACHINESPAINT")))
'        Array_Sub = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("MACHINESSUB")))
'        Array_Asy = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("MACHINESASY")))
'        Array_Facilities = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("MACHINESFACILITIES")))
        ' If data is in a single column with multiple rows
        Array_Fab = Application.Transpose(Range("MACHINESFAB")) 'referencing named ranges on the sheet
        Array_Paint = Application.Transpose(Range("MACHINESPAINT"))
        Array_Sub = Application.Transpose(Range("MACHINESSUB"))
        Array_Asy = Application.Transpose(Range("MACHINESASY"))
        Array_Facilities = Application.Transpose(Range("MACHINESFACILITIES"))
    End With

    Array_Machine_List_Choices = Array(Array_Fab, Array_Paint, Array_Sub, Array_Asy, Array_Facilities)

    MsgBox Join(Array_Machine_List_Choices(1), vbNewLine) 'see the array choices for Paint
End Sub
```

The `Application.Transpose` are a way of converting a Range to a 1D array. If you set the Array to an arrange it creates a 2D array (Even if you're only referring to one column) So with the following example

```
+----+
| A1 |
+----+
| A2 |
+----+
| A3 |
+----+
| A4 |
+----+
```

To access Element `A1` you'd have to reference it as `Array(1,1)` (not `Array(0,0)` as setting a range to an array uses `Base 1`)

By using the `Application.Tranpose` trick Excel creates a 1D array so you can refer to it as `Array(1)` instead. Which firstly makes it simpler to refer to and secondly (and more importantly) allows you to use a lot of Array functions such as `Join` and `Filter` which don't work on 2D arrays (Excel doesn't have any in-built functions for 2D arrays)

Comment: Tom, thank you so much for helping me with this!! I had to add an s to Worksheet (I forgot this originally) as well as remove the "." before the Ranges, but then it worked exactly. Can you explain what the transpose is doing?

Comment: Good spot - missed this. If they aren't in that worksheet then you can remove the `With ws` and `End With` as well. Although I'd recommend stating the ranges explicitly as in `Worksheet.Range`

Comment: Awesome. Will do. Thank you again!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a bit of an explanation for why I'm doing the `Transpose` trick

Comment: Hey Tom, I am using some of this code within a new code (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163910/excel-vba-arrays-for-data-validation-reference) but am having some difficulty solving it and issue. Would you mind taking a look when you have a moment? I thought you might be able to provide some clarity as it is further use of the arrays. Thank you again for your previous help.