# Excel VBA - Arrays for Data Validation Reference

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, validation

I have the following code:

```
Sub TEST_____________Data_Validation_Machine()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim Array_Fab As Variant
Dim Array_Paint As Variant
Dim Array_Sub As Variant
Dim Array_Asy As Variant
Dim Array_Facilities As Variant
Dim Array_Machine_List_Choices As Variant

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EOS Report")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MachineList")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PlantAreaList")

    With ws2
        'creating arrays based on the named ranges on the sheet "MachineList"
        Array_Fab = Application.Transpose(.Range("MACHINESFAB"))
        Array_Paint = Application.Transpose(.Range("MACHINESPAINT"))
        Array_Sub = Application.Transpose(.Range("MACHINESSUB"))
        Array_Asy = Application.Transpose(.Range("MACHINESASY"))
        Array_Facilities = Application.Transpose(.Range("MACHINESFACILITIES"))
    End With

        'Array of Arrays
        Array_Machine_List_Choices = Array(Array_Fab, Array_Paint, Array_Sub, Array_Asy, Array_Facilities)

    With ws3
        'creating an array based on the named range on the sheet "PlantAreaList"
        Array_Plant_Area_Choices = Application.Transpose(.Range("PlantAreaListCells"))
    End With

'Cell below "MACHINE" based on the activecell selection of the "Plant Area" combobox:
Set Range1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)

'Cell below "PLANT AREA", based on the user selection of the combobox:
Set Range3 = ActiveCell
```

For this next part, how would I code:
 if range3 = Array_Plant_Area_Choices, 
   then range2 = corresponding Array_Machine_List_Choices

```
    If Range3 = "" Then

        Set Range2 = ""

            For Each c In Range1
                If c.Interior.Pattern <> xlNone Then
                Else
                    With c.Validation
                        .Delete
                        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                            Formula1:="='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & Range2.Address
                        .IgnoreBlank = True
                        .InCellDropdown = True
                    End With
                End If
             Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This code creates a data validation box where the choices are based on a previous data validation box the user has already filled in. Currently a have a bunch of if statements to allow for each original choice, but I will be adding a ton more and this may slow down the program as well as just looking messy. I am hoping I can use arrays to make this process much cleaner.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps. Variant data type cannot hold objects, so you cannot access the range through an array.

```
Sub TEST_____________Data_Validation_Machine()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Array_Machine_List_Choices As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EOS Report")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MachineList")
    Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PlantAreaList")

    'Array of range names
    Array_Machine_List_Choices = Array("MACHINESFAB", "MACHINESPAINT", "MACHINESSUB", "MACHINESASY", "MACHINESFACILITIES")

    With ws3
        'creating an array based on the named range on the sheet "PlantAreaList"
        Array_Plant_Area_Choices = Application.Transpose(.Range("PlantAreaListCells"))
    End With

    'Cell below "MACHINE" based on the activecell selection of the "Plant Area" combobox:
    Set Range1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)

    'Cell below "PLANT AREA", based on the user selection of the combobox:
    Set Range3 = ActiveCell

    For i = 0 To UBound(Array_Plant_Area_Choices)

        If Range3 = Array_Plant_Area_Choices(i) Then

            If c.Interior.Pattern = xlNone Then
                With c.Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                        Formula1:="='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & Array_Machine_List_Choices(i)
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi newacc2240, thank you for your response. Let me try it and Ill get back to you!

Comment: @newacc2440, I tried to incorporate what you had into what I have, as I still need it to work for the data validation boxes. I updated the code above to show the changes. However, I get error 9, subscript out of range on the "If Range3.Value" line...

Comment: What is the value of `i`?

Comment: I have a named range "PlantAreaListCells" which contains a few different areas such as "Fab", "Paint", etc. Basically I want it to say, if the user chooses a dropdown option of Paint, then give the corresponding Array_Paint values in the next dropdown box. I am wanting to use i as a placeholder so that if they pick any of the given options, they get the corresponding values in the next dropdown menu. I was able to due this using a ton of if then statements, but to simplify I was hoping to use arrays.

Comment: I mean, what is the value of `i` when the macro went wrong? Did you put these code inside a ForLoop?

Comment: Oh, it was "Asy/Post" in this case which refers to the Array_Asy array.

Comment: And no, I had added your function up above my original code. I could try the forloop though.

Comment: You HAVE to put it inside a for loop. If you don't, excel takes it as `0` and won't change it at all.

Comment: I went ahead and changed it to encompass the for loop (see update above), however I got runtime error 91

Comment: You have to `Set Range2` first. Range2 is a Range Object and it is `Nothing` right now.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and help! I put the set right before range2, but it throws the same error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158444/discussion-between-newacc2240-and-mitchmitch24).